# Best Approach to refresh RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a situation where i need to update the recyclerview once something got posted in the server.

For example if some new news got posted in the server & if my android application is open it should reflect in the recyclerView.
I have done some workarround & have some few solutions too as follows

1)Using SwipeToRefresh method

2)Using RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

3)using some background thread or service(Last Option)

but which one is the best or any other suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: 3) Use service at first

Comment: Both [1] and [2] Swipe to refresh will refresh the recycler view if the user wishes and further refreshing on scrolling would offer the best experience in terms of performance.

Comment: Consumes more battery @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Why not push ? When a news is published you will get a push notification and you will just call yourAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged().

Comment: If in a day 1000 news got posted then 1000 notification will come thats really...not cool @Mi

Comment: As you mentioned, when your android application is open, the going with option 2 is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever your are getting a new post from your server, ask them to send a silent push with the post details. You can add that data to your data list and just notify the adapter to change as notifyDataSetChanged. That will work.

Answer (score 1):

3rd approach will be best.You should run  a background task to fetch the items and when you receive new item ,add it to the local list you are passing to the recycler view and the call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**EDIT**
you should only keep the background task running when the user is inside the activity,else you should close it.This is will result in optimized performance

Answer (score -3):

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This is not what the user asked, Senor.

Comment: SwipeRefreshLayout
NotifyDatasetChanged